# SQL INSERT VALUES INTO TABLE FROM FILE

Tags: php, mysql, sql, pdo

I would like to Insert some values into my table from a file. I do the following

```
$stmt=$db->prepare(INSERT INTO Info VALUES (NOW(), LOAD DATA INFILE "insert.txt"));
$stmt->execute();
```

I get the following error message: Parse Error syntax error unexpected T_STRING on line 6...

Comment: You have syntax error in your code.

Comment: Try using quotes around your query string.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Both your PHP and your MySQL syntax have problems. First, your SQL statement needs to be surrounded by quotes. Secondly, the syntax for [`LOAD DATA INFILE`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/load-data.html) is incorrect. Try this:

```
$stmt=$db->prepare("LOAD DATA INFILE 'insert.txt' into table `Info`");
$stmt->execute();
```

See the [MySQL docs for `LOAD DATA INFILE`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/load-data.html) for more options. You'll probably need to specify your field and line delimiters, for instance. If you need to set a column to the value of the `now()` function, you can issue a separate `update` query for that.

Answer (score 4):

```
  $db->prepare("LOAD DATA INFILE 'insert.txt'    
   INTO TABLE `Info`
  FIELDS TERMINATED BY ',' 
  ENCLOSED BY '\"' 
  LINES TERMINATED BY '\n' 
  IGNORE 1 LINES 
  (`your`, `colums`)
  SET `your_time` = NOW()")
  ->execute();
```

Use ignore lines, set the table names, and insert the NOW() with SET

Comment: what is supposed to go in the (your tables) ?

Comment: the name of your colums.

Comment: Your code does not work! @john